# Replace brackets around items with array

Tags: regex, vim

In my file, I have lots of lines containing something like

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

which I need to replace with

```
array('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Decided to try to figure out how to use vim to do the replacement, but the best I got was to match `[` and `]` individually. What's the proper way to do this in one regex? I'm assuming it has something to do with back-reference.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a capturing group.

```
:%s/\[\(.*\)]/array(\1)
```

Find everything between square brackets replace the outside keeping whatever was in the middle.

Comment: Just be careful if two such `[` lists are in the same line

Comment: @A.E.Drew You could change it to the non greedy version but then you have to worry about nested ones. Not really sure which is better.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use Tim Pope's [surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin.

```
cs]farray<cr>
```

This reads like so: `cs`, change surrounding `]` to a function (`f`), `array`. Now you can just use `.` to repeat the action on any bracket structure.

Comment: Is this documented some where?

Comment: @FDinoff the function replacements (`f`, `F`, `<c-f>`) are sadly not in the documentation. Neither is the LaTex tags (``\`` or `l`) nor the ruby/lisp symbol (`:`) replacements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a perl one-liner; run it in you shell:

```
# Assuming entries like ['a', 'b', 'c'] are in file.txt
perl -pi -e 's/\[(.*)\]/array\($1\)/g' file.txt
# ['a', 'b', 'c'] changed to array('a', 'b', 'c') in file.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the Vim substitute command.

```
:%s/['a', 'b', 'c']/array('a', 'b', 'c')/g
```

Comment: This will only work for ['a', 'b', 'c']. What about things like ['g', 1, 'c', 'hello']?